# How to use log scale with Chart Kick?

Tags: vue.js, chart.js, chartkick

I'm trying to use a log scale instead of linear scale, my code is:

html

```
<line-chart :data="datafor"></line-chart>
```

JS

```
datafor = {
          name: "Test name",
          data: objectHere,
          library: {
            legend: {
              position: "bottom"
            },
            scales: {
              yAxes: [
                {
                  id: "y-axis",
                  type: "logarithmic"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        };
}
```

The code above is still just giving me a linear scale line chart, any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It was a simple fix, I making a stupid mistake by passing the libary options into my data object.

I fixed it by doing the following:

html:

```
<line-chart :library="chartOption":data="datafor"></line-chart>
```

js

```
chartOption = {
          legend: {
            position: "top"
          },
          scales: {
            yAxes: [
              {
                id: "y-axis",
                type: "logarithmic"
              }
            ]
          }
        };

       datafor[i] = {
          name: "Test name",
          data: objectHere,
          title: "test"
        };
      }
```